# Search between 2 Dates in double format instead of Date fomat VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, date

I am working on VB.NET 2015 and MS Access Database
I was working in converting date to Double Format but I faced some problems when I created reports in converting dates from Double to Date format again.
I decided to work with Dates Type again, Changed the Database Field to Date/Time and used the following code.

```
 Private Sub SearchInvoiceByDate()

    Dim InvDateFrom As Double
    InvDateFrom = dtpFromDate.Value.Date.ToOADate
    Dim InvDateTo As Double
    InvDateTo = dtpToDate.Value.Date.ToOADate

    'Dim InvDateFrom As Date
    'InvDateFrom = dtpFromDate.Value.Date
    'Dim InvDateTo As Date
    'InvDateTo = dtpToDate.Value.Date

    objdataset.Clear()
    DGPurchaseReport.DataSource = Nothing
    DGPurchaseReport.ColumnCount = 0

    ConnectDatabse()

    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = myConnection
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select * from Invoice where Invoice_Date BETWEEN " & InvDateFrom & " and  " & InvDateTo & ""
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    myConnection.Open()
    objDataAdapter.Fill(objdataset, "Invoice")

    DGPurchaseReport.DataSource = objdataset
    DGPurchaseReport.DataMember = "Invoice"
```

I forget to change InvDateFrom/TO format to Date , and it is working fine and I get the desired result. whenever I change InvDateFrom/TO to Date I get no result. 
I was wondering why it works this way however when I open my Database the date format is date like 17/03/2017.

When I put this code:

```
Dim InvDateFrom As Date
InvDateFrom = dtpFromDate.Value.Date
Dim InvDateTo As Date
InvDateTo = dtpToDate.Value.Date
```

I get no result.

dtpFrom/dtpToDate are DateTimePicker with customFOrmat:

```
dtpFromDate.CustomFormat = "ddMMyyyy"
    dtpToDate.CustomFormat = "ddMMyyyy"
```

One more thing , I get the invoice_Date in date format 17/03/2017 in the DataGridView although I search in double.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pass your dates as parameters and see how that affects your results.

Comment: @Andrew Mortimer thank you for your response, it worked !! 
I am not sure why but It works fine know.
By the way I tried both variable Types "Double" and "Date" , I get the same result.Thank you again.